# Identifying gradient filled region

Tags: image-processing

I asked a related question before: [Image segmentations with gradient filled regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544976/image-segmentations-with-gradient-filled-regions)

But this time, I have a more simpler problem (I think). Given a region (set of pixels), I want to know if it is filled with a linear gradient. To do this, I thought of finding out image gradient in x and y direction using 3X3 sobel filter and then examine the direction of gradient. If this direction remains constant, then the region may be classified as gradient filled region.

It works for horizontal and vertical direction gradients but not in general. For example, it seems that for a 45 degree linear gradient, the direction of gradient is quite varying on neighboring pixels between 1 to 3.

I am not able to understand why this is happening and how to fix it. Theoretically, it should be 1 everywhere.

Comment: If you think about the gradient in terms of subsequent colored lines, you see that drawing a non-straight line (rotated) requires one or more segmentation. Not in the real world, I mean, but pixels are limited in an image.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_filter#cite_note-1) says:

The Sobel operator, while reducing artifacts associated with a pure central differences operator, **does not have perfect rotational symmetry**. Scharr looked into optimizing this property. Filter kernels up to size 5 x 5 have been presented there, but the most frequently used one is ...

Here's Sharr's paper, happy studying :) 
http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/volltexte/2000/962/pdf/Diss.pdf

Comment: Is there an english version available?

Comment: don't know, you could ask the authors or use a translator, even if they perform poorly

Answer (score 1):

You have the idea right, just use Gaussian filters when you compute the spatial derivatives.
Finally, get the gradient filled areas by selecting the dark pixels of the orientation image's gradient magnitude.

**EDIT** 
Wikipedia article on [Gaussian filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Gaussian_kernel).

In my code, I use the following convolution kernels (horizontal then vertical derivatives):

```
{
 {0.00623304, 0.012975, 0., -0.012975, -0.00623304},
 {0.0259501, 0.054019, 0., -0.054019, -0.0259501},
 {0.0581332, 0.121013, 0., -0.121013, -0.0581332},
 {0.0259501, 0.054019, 0., -0.054019, -0.0259501},
 {0.00623304, 0.012975, 0., -0.012975, -0.00623304}
}

{
 {0.00623304, 0.0259501, 0.0581332, 0.0259501, 0.00623304},
 {0.012975, 0.054019, 0.121013, 0.054019, 0.012975},
 {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.},
 {-0.012975, -0.054019, -0.121013, -0.054019, -0.012975},
 {-0.00623304, -0.0259501, -0.0581332, -0.0259501, -0.00623304}
}
```

As a proof of concept, this is how it could look in Mathematica, using a test image which contains a slanted gradient region and a vertical gradient region:

[image]

Comment: I dont know mathmatica so I dont understand it quite well, but I can sense what you suggested. So far, I have tried smoothing the original image with gaussian blur before applying sobel filter but it does not fix my problem. Are you suggesting something different? Also, you images seem to use a horizontal or vertical direction gradient, did you try on an angular gradient say 45 degrees?

Comment: You see the image contains both slanted and vertical gradient-filled regions. I have edited my answer to add the convolution kernels. You can use them in your preferred convolution engine.